# How to "correctly" update my apps on PlayStore

Tags: react-native, google-play, google-play-console

have a nice day for all of you, I have a question, it's a bit silly actually, but I'm very curious and until now I still don't know why this happened.

So I have an application, and it is already `live on the PlayStore`, and every time I update my application via the PlayStore console, `why do I seem to download the entire application?` even though I only did very little update (on coding), I `only added 1 line` to get rid of the bug.

Why did this happen? Shouldn't it be that if I do a small update to the code, when I update through my device it only updates with a small size too?

Oh yes, I did an update on the playstore console by `Create new Release`, is this the right thing? Or have I been wrong all this time?

I'm using `.aab` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin provides client-side integration for the CodePush service, allowing you to easily add a dynamic update experience to your React Native app(s) Android/IOS.

[react-native-code-push](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-code-push)

Comment: OK DUDE, this is 100% legit! thanks for your advice!!